# Parsing a nested api response in Node

Tags: node.js

An API request like this: `const response = await this.publicGetMarkets (params);` is giving me a response that contains a list of `markets` in the following format:

```json
{
  "markets": {
    "LINK-USD": {
    "market": "LINK-USD",
    "status": "ONLINE"
  },
  ...
}
```

As in the example here, my problem is that `LINK-USD` is changing for every market.
How do I fix my code so that I can variables such as `market`, `status` in my code.
I have written the following code snippet:

```js
const market = this.safeValue (response, 'markets');
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < markets.length; i++) {
       const markets = this.safeString (markets, {}, {});
       const market = this.safeString (markets, 'market');
       const status = this.safeString (markets, 'status');
       result.push({
           'market': market,
           'status': status,
        });
     }
     return result;
```

Comment: Can you share the `safeString` method

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all the inner objects using `Object.values(data.markets)`.

If you need to filter out unwanted properties that is a fairly simple mapping addition to this also

```js
const data = {
  "markets": {
    "LINK-USD": {
      "market": "LINK-USD",
      "status": "ONLINE"
    },
    "LINK-EURO": {
      "market": "LINK-EURO",
      "status": "TBD"
    }
  }
}

const res = Object.values(data.markets)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const responses = this.safeValue (response, 'markets');
    const result = [];
    for (let response of responses) {
       const market = responses.markets["LINK-USD"].market,
       status = responses.markets["LINK-USD"].status;
       result.push({market, status});
     }
     return result;
```

I hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: Its not valid Javascript. Key names cannot have hyphens in them; you'll need to use square bracket notation rather than dot notation for `LINK-USD`

Comment: I've edited your answer to fix, and also changed the unnecessary `let` to a const.

Comment: Also, `LINK-USD` is an example of the first occurrence but the name will change for every other occurrence. One of the problems is: how do I access the objects under `LINK-USD` programatically. Regardless of what variable replaces `LINK-USD`.